# std::string can be passed as nlohmann::json to explicit constructor

Tags: c++, nlohmann-json

Why does the following code compile, even though I am passing a `std::string` object to a **explicit** constructor which expects a `nlohmann::json` [(to the library)](https://github.com/nlohmann/json) object? My understanding is that `std::string` won't be implicit converted due to the `explicit` keyword.
Is it possible to change my code so that it will compile successful only when a `nlohmann::json` is passed?

I use Visual Studio 2019 in Debug Mode with `/Wall`.

```
#include <nlohmann/json.hpp>

struct A {
    explicit A(nlohmann::json json) {

    }
};

int main() {
    std::string a = "hello";
    A b(a);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does the following code compile, even though I am passing a `std::string` object to a **explicit** constructor which expects a `nlohmann::json` (to the library) object? My understanding is that `std::string` won't be implicit converted due to the `explicit` keyword.

The `explicit` in the `A` constructor just means that the `A` constructor must be called explicitly (which you are). The compiler is allowed to use implicit conversions when passing arguments to the `A` constructor, unless they use types that are also `explicit` themselves (which the `nlohmann::json` constructor is not).

> Is it possible to change my code so that it will compile successful only when a `nlohmann::json` is passed?

You can pass the argument by a non-const reference, preventing the compiler from passing an implicitly created temporary object:

```cpp
struct A {
    explicit A(nlohmann::json &json) {
    }
};
```

Comment: So there's no possibility to change this behaviour without altering the source code of `nlohmann::json`?

Comment: Thanks, passing as a reference fixed my issue ;)

Answer (score 1):

This might be overkill but the following appears to work while also allowing a const-reference as constructor argument:

```cpp
#include <nlohmann/json.hpp>
#include <type_traits>

struct A {
    template<typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<T, nlohmann::json>>>
    explicit A(const T& json) {

    }
};

int main() {
    const std::string a = "hello";
    // A b(a); // ERROR
    
    const auto json_val = nlohmann::json::parse("{}") ;
    A c {json_val} ;
}
```